# Как вызвать из компонента метод дочернего компонента?

Tags: vue.js

Здравствуйте.

Полный нуб в Vue и до этого не сталкивался с подобными библиотеками.

Есть компонент и я хочу вызвать метод дочернего компонента. И не могу понять как это правильно сделать. По документации я понимаю что могу только значение передать(props), а событие вызвать может только дочерний компонент у родителя. Пробовал через $on\$emit, но ни ошибки ни результата.

Или правильно значение в переданном параметре через props и отслеживать его в дочернем, если изменился то запустить метод.

В общем в полном не понимании, направьте пожалуйста в нужное направление.

Заранее спасибо!

Родительский компонент:

```
<template>
    <b-tab v-on:click="initReviews" title="Отзывы">
        <reviews></reviews>
    </b-tab>
</template>

<script type="text/babel">
    import reviews from './reviews/reviews.vue';

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
            }
        },
        components:{
            reviews
        },
        methods:{
            initReviews:function(){
                console.log("Click reviews tab! init ...");
                // Как тут обратиться к reviews.init() ?
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Дочерний компонент:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-if="showLoader">Загружаем отзывы ...</div>
        <div v-else>список отзывов!</div>
    </div>
</template>

<script type="text/babel">
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                showLoader:true,
            }
        },
        methods:{
            init:function () {
                console.log("child init ...");
                this.showLoader = false;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прокидывайте showLoader пропсом в дочерний, если решили контролировать.

Comment: Так перед тем как снять блок "загрузка" нужно подтянуть отзывы с сервера. Это нужно ставить слушателя на этот пропс в дочернем компоненте на изменения значения?

Comment: Зависит от вашего кейса. Но то что предлагаете вы, это конкрЭтный антипаттерн.

Comment: Можете тогда шаги действий подсказать? Понимаю что антипаттерн, а как правильно не понимаю.

Comment: Конечно. Вот вам пример
https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KtSlC70vEVyoQ9egOLl

Comment: Спасибо огромное, буду пробовать!

Answer (score 0):

Используйте defineExpose для предоставления доступа к функции дочернего компонента. Обратиться к ней из родителя можно через ссылку ref='yourFunction'

```
<script setup>
  //child component
  function myFunction() {
    console.log('I'm Works!');
  }
  defineExpose({ 
  myfunction,
  });
</script>

<script setup>
  //parent component
  import { ref } from vue;
  const useFunction = ref(null)
  useFunction.value.myFunction()
</script>

<template>
  <MyChildComponent ref="useFunction" />
</template>
```